# Why can't I insert values to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a problem with a part of my program in Python 3.7.

It's a program, where you can add vocabulary with their translation in any language to a .txt file and this program can ask you a word and you enter the translation - this is working fine.

Receiving this data works also very good. But I also want to save the two languages, which you enter in the program, to this .txt file.

I can add these two to the first line of the .txt file and if I try to print the first line of this file it also works, but I need to split the two values of the text file, because they are written like this in the text file (f.e):
`German - English`

Finally I want to add this two split values to a new list. But if I try to print the first value of the list, I get following error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

and if I check if the list is empty, I can see that it is empty, but why?

Thanks for your help

This is my code, which is responsible for this error:

```
new_currSprache = []

with open(name + ".txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for lines[0] in file.readlines():
        lang_1, lang_2 = lines[0].split(" - ")
        print(lang_1)
        print(lang_2)
        new_currLanguage.append(lang_1, lang_2)
    firstLanguage = new_currLanguage[0]
    secondLanguage = new_currLanguage[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to go through all the lines, and `split` already returns a list

```
with open(name + ".txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    new_currLanguage  = lines[0].split(" - ")
    firstLanguage = new_currLanguage[0]
    secondLanguage = new_currLanguage[1]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!!! Yes, it was stupid to go through all the lines :)
Thank you very much!!!